# Laravel:Failed to retrieve image from storage

Tags: laravel-5

I have a function that store image to the storage/app/images

```
  $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        if ($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $request->file('image')->storeAs('images', $filename);
        }

        $creator = new Content_form([
            'media_id' => $request->get('media_name'),
            'content_title' => $request->get('content_title'),
            'content_description' => $request->get('content_description'),
            'date_occured' =>\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
            'page_number' => $request->get('page_number'),
            'image' => $filename,
        ]);
        $creator->save();
```

Image is stored in the database and in the storage/app/image only failed to retrieve those image here is my blade

```
@foreach($pendingNews as $number=> $post)
                        <td style="font-size: 16px; width: 210px"><img class="img-rounded" width="150" height="130" src="{{  asset('storage/app/images/'.$post->image) }}"></td>
            @endforeach
```

Also file system I have

```
   'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan storage:link` to link your storage folder into the public directory?

Comment: yes I run php artisan storage:link

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/app` from `asset('storage/app/images/'.$post->image)`

Comment: I have done this                                                                                           <td"><img src="{{  asset('storage/images/'.$post->image) }}"></td>
still no image shown